# Dreamweaver live preview not using CSS stylesheet and other references

Tags: javascript, html, css, dreamweaver

new to web design and Dreamweaver! I'm playing around with a simple website with an HTML file called index.html, a stylesheet called style.css, and a JavaScript file called entry.js. They are at the same directory level in my project and I have referenced them in my index.html. The Live feature is properly showing it but when I try to open it up on my browser, it is giving me just the barebone HTML file without any of the style or functionality. Do you know why that is? I have attached my HTML code below.

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>The Field Book</title>
    <link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "/style.css">
    <script src = "/entry.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <center>
        <button onclick = "JavaScript:revealPage()">the field book</button>
    <p id = "hiddenPhotos" style = "display:none">      
        <img src="images/CypressHomePageButton.jpg" width="400" height="450" alt=""/>
        <img src="images/NasturtiumHomePageButton.jpg" width="450" height="550" alt=""/>
        </p>
        
    </center>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hm can you take a picture of your file tree and post it in your answer just to make sure that the paths are correct? Also, it is good practice to move the `script` tag to the bottom of your `body` tag, as there can be a chance that the script is loading before the HTML does.

Comment: first at all, `index.html` is the default page in any server structure unless another default page has been delcared via `.htaccess` as example. Then dont use a slash at the start of they css href unless you want to move up another folder. Then last but not least, `<center></center>`  is an old tag from HTML4 times. If you just starting web development, you should start with the modern techniques/methods and tags of HTML5 where you center etxts through css with `text-align: center;` Same counts by wrapping images within a paragraph `<p>` which is un-necessary and a bad use

Answer (score 0):

Since your files are all in the same directory, try taking out the slash (/) before the Javascript and css files. '/' in relative URLs means the root of the site, but you want the current directory. So your code should read as follows:

```
<link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "style.css">
<script src = "entry.js"></script>
```

Comment: this will not cause the issue. This could have been given as a comemnt (as it already was stated) but not as an anwser. Espacially in this case as this would mean a typo error and then wouldnt meet the SO guidelines. Not having the priviledges for giving comments, do not mean that you can misuse the answer option for it.